# access array from struct in C

Tags: struct, multidimensional-array, field

In my `data.h` file I have:

```
typedef struct {
    double ***grid;
} Solver;
```

In my `.c` file I have

```
static Solver _solver;
```

which first makes a call to a function to do some allocation on grid such as

```
_solver.grid = malloc(....);

//then makes a call to

GS_init(_solver.grid);
```

The GS_init function is declared in `GS.h` as:

```
void GS_init(double ***grid);
```

When I try to compile, I get two errors:

```
the struct "<unnamed>" has no field "grid"
GS_init(_solver.grid)
^
```

and

```
too many arguments in function call
GS_init(_solver.grid)
^
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Be scared when you see triple pointers.  They are occasionally a good idea; they are very seldom a good idea.

Comment: Does GS.h include data.h?  Superficially, if both headers are in included in the code in your '.c' file, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: gs.h and data.h are separate files. I have already modified the code to use a triple pointer (3d array) and it ran a lot faster. Now I am trying ot move the local copy of the data I had in my method back out to the solver structure.

Comment: oh, yes, i see what you were saying now. yes, in the .c file, both are included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code compiles with 'gcc -Wall -Werror -c':

#### data.h

```
typedef struct
{
    double ***grid;
} Solver;
```

#### gs.h

```
extern void GS_init(double ***grid);
```

#### gs.c

```
#include "data.h"
#include "gs.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

static Solver _solver;

void anonymous(void)
{
    _solver.grid = malloc(32 * sizeof(double));
    GS_init(_solver.grid);
}
```

---

Derek asked:

> Why does this work? Is it because of the extern keyword?

The 'extern' is not material to making it work, though I always use it.

> When I have to flesh out GS_init() in, say compute.c, would I write `void GS_init(double ***grid){ //loop over grid[i][j][k] setting to zero }`

Sort of...yes, the GS_init() code could do that if the data structure is set up properly, which is going to need more information than there is currently visible in the structure.

For the compiler to process:

```
grid[i][j][k] = 0.0;
```

the code has to know the valid ranges for each of i, j, and k; assume the number of rows in each dimension are N<sub>i</sub>, N<sub>j</sub>, N<sub>k</sub>.  The data 'structure' pointed to by `grid` must be an array of N<sub>i</sub> 'double **' values - which must be allocated.  Each of those entries must point to N<sub>j</sub> 'double *' values.  So, you have to do more allocation than a single `malloc()`, and you have to do more initialization than just setting everything to zero.

If you want to use a single array of doubles only, you will have to write a different expression to access the data:

```
grid[(i * Ni + j) * Nj + k] = 0.0;
```

And under this scenario, `grid` would be a simple `double *` and not a triple pointer.

Comment: why does this work? because of the extern keyword? when I have to flesh out GS_init() in, say compute.c, would i write
   void GS_init(double ***grid){ 
   //loop over grid[i][j][k] setting to zero 
   }

Comment: It should be `Ni` and `Nj`, not `Ni-1` and `Nj-1`.

Comment: @BlueRaja: yes, you're right; thanks.  Too long since I had to do this sort of stuff.